# Can't convert Keras model to tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model saved with the following line:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, "path/to/model.h5")
```

Later, I try to convert it to a `tflite` file as follows:

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('path/to/model.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("path/to/model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But I get a weird error:

> You are trying to load a weight file containing 35 layers into a model with 0 layers.

I know that my model is working fine. I am able to load it and draw inferences. This error only shows up when trying to save it as a tflite model.

TensorFlow version: tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0

I'm using tf.keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the issue is due to explicitly defining an `InputLayer` with some `input_shape`.

My model was of the form:

> InputLayer(input_shape=(...))
>
> BatchNormalization()
>
> .... Remaining layers

I changed it to:

> BatchNormalization(input_shape=(...))
>
> .... Remaining layers

and transferred the weights from the previous model here. Now it works perfectly.